# Open Labyrinth на Checkio

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Условия задачи:**

*У лабиринта нет стен, но он окружен кустами по внешним краям. Если игрок зашел в куст, то он проиграл. Лабиринт представлен как матрица (список (list) списков): 1 - это куст и 0 - это дорожка. Размер лабиринта 12 на 12 клеток и внешние клетки всегда кусты. Игрок начинает в клетке (1, 1). Выход в клетке (10, 10). Вам нужно найти маршрут через Лабиринт. Игрок может двигатся только в четырех направлениях -- Юг (вниз [1,0]), Север (вверх [-1,0]), Восток (вправо [0,1]), Запад (влево [0, -1]). Маршрут описывается строкой состоящей из следующих символов: "S"=Юг, "N"=Север, "E"=Восток, and "W"=Запад.*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
from typing import List

result = []
visited = [[1, 1]]


def checkio(maze_map: List[List[int]]) -> str:
    i, j = 1, 1
    lab = maze_map
    moving(i, j, lab)
    print(visited)

    return ''.join(str(e) for e in result)


def moving(i, j, lab):
    if (lab[i][j - 1] == 0) and ([i, j - 1] not in visited):
        j -= 1
        result.append('W')
        visited.append([i, j])
        print('i, j: ', i, j)
    elif (lab[i][j + 1] == 0) and ([i, j + 1] not in visited):
        j += 1
        result.append('E')
        visited.append([i, j])
        print('i, j: ', i, j)
    elif (lab[i + 1][j] == 0) and ([i + 1, j] not in visited):
        i += 1
        result.append('S')
        visited.append([i, j])
        print('i, j: ', i, j)
    elif (lab[i - 1][j] == 0) and ([i - 1, j] not in visited):
        i -= 1
        result.append('N')
        visited.append([i, j])
        print('i, j: ', i, j)
    if i != 10 and j != 10:
        moving(visited[-1][0], visited[-1][1], lab)
```

Я не понимаю почему мой код работает не корректно, конечно он не идеален, я уже сейчас вижу 2 глобальные проблемы, которые поставят меня в тупик при таком подходе. Но всё же хотел бы разобраться почему :

Мой вывод(черным помечу проблемные места): [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], **[1, 8]**, [1, 9], [1, 10], **[2, 1]**, [3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 1], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 8], [8, 9], **[8, 10]**]

- Почему не делает поворот на [1,8] ?
- Почему код останавливается на [8,10] ?
- Почему после [1,10] происходит прыжок в [2, 1] ?

Вот проверочный код от разработчика задачи:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(checkio([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]))


    # This code using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    def check_route(func, labyrinth):
        MOVE = {"S": (1, 0), "N": (-1, 0), "W": (0, -1), "E": (0, 1)}
        # copy maze
        route = func([row[:] for row in labyrinth])
        pos = (1, 1)
        goal = (10, 10)
        for i, d in enumerate(route):
            move = MOVE.get(d, None)
            if not move:
                print("Wrong symbol in route")
                return False
            pos = pos[0] + move[0], pos[1] + move[1]
            if pos == goal:
                return True
            if labyrinth[pos[0]][pos[1]] == 1:
                print("Player in the pit")
                return False
        print("Player did not reach exit")
        return False


    # These assert are using only for self-testing as examples.
    assert check_route(checkio, [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), "First maze"
    assert check_route(checkio, [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), "Empty maze"
    assert check_route(checkio, [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), "Up and down maze"
    assert check_route(checkio, [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), "Dotted maze"
    assert check_route(checkio, [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), "Need left maze"
    assert check_route(checkio, [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]), "The big dead end."
    print("The local tests are done.")
```

Comment: Вопрос очень хорошо составлен, плюс уже хотя бы за это :)

Comment: Такую задачу не получится решить линейно. Придется использовать, например, рекурсию или очереди, иначе зайдя в тупик вы не сможете вернуться и попробовать другой маршрут.

Comment: @extrn если я правильно понимаю, то рекурсия это когда ваша функция вызывает саму себя, в моём случае, чтобы избежать запирания в тупике и прогнать все возможные повороты -  я использую запуск функции moving ещё раз, вот тут, откатываемся к последнему пройденному месту и прогоняем все варианты движений . Этот момент 100% нужно дорабатывать, но пока вроде эта проблема не актуальна    `if i == 10 and j == 10:
        return ''.join(str(e) for e in result)
    else:
        moving(visited[-1][0], visited[-1][1], lab)`

Comment: Да, рекурсия это вызов функцией самой себя, но что важнее, это удобное средство для составление древовидного (а не просто зацикленного) алгоритма. А ваша реализация пока слишком далека от правильного решения, и простой доработки тут будет недостаточно.

Comment: @extrn не могли бы, Вы, подтолкнуть меня в сторону правильного решения конкретно на моём примере?

Comment: Я пытаюсь вам объяснить, что ваш пример не получится исправить, чтобы он стал рабочим. его придется переписать с нуля по совершенно другому алгоритму, нет смысла объяснять на нем. Он вообще должен был бы повиснуть на всех приведенных тестах, если бы не ошибка в условии `i != 10 and j != 10` (должно быть `i != 10 or j != 10`)

Comment: @extrn я убрал while и добавил рекурсию, код отредактировал, прошу Вас посмотреть на вывод, он идёт прям к направлению выхода, не хватает сделать всего 1 поворот, почему он не доходит? срабатывает ошибка проверки "Player in the pit", я не понимаю как такая ошибка может возникнуть, если у меня везде стоит условие на "1"

Comment: @extrn вот рабочий код от другого пользователя: 
`def checkio(data):
    result = []
    dirs = [[-1, 0, "W"], [+1, 0, "E"], [0, -1, "N"], [0, +1, "S"]]
    def move(path, x, y, field):
        field[y][x] = 1
        if x == 10 and y == 10:
            result.append(path)
        for d in dirs:
            if field[y + d[1]][x + d[0]] == 0:
                move(path + d[2], x + d[0], y + d[1], field)
    move("", 1, 1, data)
    return result[0]`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100744/discussion-between-extrn-and-frazer).

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка означает, что объектом итерирования оказалось `None`, в вашем случае это `route` является `None`:

```
for i, d in enumerate(route):
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Поиск по вопросу показывает, что только в одном месте `route` есть:

```
def check_route(func, labyrinth):
    MOVE = {"S": (1, 0), "N": (-1, 0), "W": (0, -1), "E": (0, 1)}
    # copy maze
    route = func([row[:] for row in labyrinth])
```

А в `func` попадет ссылка на вашу функцию, которая в `else` не возвращает ничего из функции (нет `return`). Если функция явно ничего не возвращает, тогда из функции вернется `None`.

Т.е. перепишите функцию так, чтобы она в любом случае возвращала строку по условию задачи:

```
def checkio(maze_map: List[List[int]]) -> str:
    i, j = 1, 1
    lab = maze_map
    moving(i, j, lab)
    print(visited)
    if i == 10 and j == 10:
        return ''.join(str(e) for e in result)
    else:
        moving(visited[-1][0], visited[-1][1], lab)  # <- Вот тут нужен return

    # <- Или тут будет return
```

Comment: спасибо, ошибка ушла, теперь просто не проходит первую проверку :)

Comment: @Frazer, у вас, значит где-то неправильно алгоритм реализован (не смотрел), а так запускайте проверочный код от разработчика задачи и смотрите почему у вас не совпадает. А [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)